# Why does Excel give me a false value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

2,5+4,5=7, right? I didn't understand why Excel is giving me a false value in this case.

I'm sorry my Excel is in Portuguese.

Comment: Are your numbers really formatted as numbers? And what does "=J13+K13" give (so you leave out =7)?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the formula that returns `FALSE`. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because excel is storing those values as floating-point numbers, not as decimals. So, you're really working with values that are rounded to `4.500000x` and `2.5000000x`, and their sum is likewise `7.0000000x` and not exactly equal to the integer 7.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113

> When numbers are stored, a corresponding binary number can represent
>   every number or fractional number. For example, the fraction 1/10 can
>   be represented in a decimal number system as 0.1. However, the same
>   number in binary format becomes the following repeating binary
>   decimal: 0001100110011100110011 (and so on) This can be infinitely
>   repeated. This number cannot be represented in a finite (limited)
>   amount of space. Therefore, this number is rounded down by
>   approximately -2.8E-17 when it is stored.
>   …
>    Excel offers two basic methods to compensate for rounding errors: the
>   ROUND function and the Precision as displayed or Set precision as
>   displayed workbook option.
>
> The following example uses the ROUND function to force a number to five digits. This lets you successfully compare the result to another
>   value.
>
> > A1: 1.2E+200
> >       B1: 1E+100
> >     C1: =ROUND(A1+B1,5)
>
> In some cases, you may be able to prevent rounding errors from affecting your work by using the Precision as displayed option.
>   [click Options, and then click the Advanced category.]
>   [ In the calculating this workbook section, select the Set precision as displayed check box.]